# Router is undefined in react-router v2.0.0 after import

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to use react-router v2.0.0 and when I use `import { Router, Route, browserHistory } from 'react-router'` and then `console.log(Router)` I get that Router is undefined.  However, when I log Route, it outputs the correct object.

```
"use strict";

import React from 'react'
import { Router, Route, browserHistory } from 'react-router'
import Home from './pages/home.js'
import Entrance from './pages/Entrance.js'
import Courses from './pages/Courses.js'
import Quizzes from './pages/Quizzes.js'

console.log("conner", Router);
console.log("conner", Route);

module.exports = (
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Home}>
      <Route path="entrance" component={Entrance} />
      <Route path="courses" component={Courses} />
      <Route path="quizzes" component={Quizzes} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
);
```

This all results in this console error: `Uncaught Invariant Violation: ReactDOM.render(): Invalid component element. This may be caused by unintentionally loading two independent copies of React`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you upgrading from some old version from React or React Router? If yes, try delete node_modules folder and run `sudo npm install`

Comment: The version used to be 0.13.3, but I have already updated the Router to 2.0.0 in package.json and I have deleted npm_modules and ran npm install --save.  Is there something else I might be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you go into your node_modules and into react-router to check its version in its package.json?

Answer (score 0):

If you go on the directory where you have your web project and you just type : npm ls | grep react .

If you see react appearing multiple times then you have dependencies problems as some modulues installed newer versions of react on top of an older version breaking everything.

You can try npm shrinkwrap, npm prune, fixing your package.json.

You can refer to this post about shrinkwrap:
http://javascript.tutorialhorizon.com/2015/03/21/what-is-npm-shrinkwrap-and-when-is-it-needed/